# @selector throwing error in different methods

Tags: objective-c

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(createBlogPosts:) withObject:false];
    self.progressBar.alpha = 0.0;
}

//actual method here
-(void)createBlogPosts:(BOOL)refresh

- (IBAction)refreshButtonPressed {
    //[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(createBlogPosts:) withObject:false];
    [self performSelector:@selector(createBlogPosts:) withObject:true]; 
}
```

a) i don’t understand fully what @selectors are
b) in view did load, [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(createBlogPosts:) withObject:false] compiles just fine and works as expected. yet when my refreshButtonPressed Action is triggered, and i try to run the same method, just with a different parameter (wouldn’t matter if i had false either way) i get 2 errors:

(caution) incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending ‘int’ to parameter of type ‘id’
(warning) implicit conversion of ‘int’ to ‘id’ is disallowed with ARC

any help to someone who is new to coding would be great! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The performSelector:withObject: is expecting an object. BOOL is not an object so it will give that error.

A possible solution is to make your method receive a NSNumber `createBlogPosts:(NSNumber *)value` and then make something like:

```
NSNumber *passedValue = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
[self performSelector:@selector(createBlogPosts:) withObject:passedValue];
```

And in the method:

```
-(void)createBlogPosts:(NSNumber *)value {
   BOOL value = [value boolValue];
}
```

**Extra info:**
`Why it does not crash in the viewDidLoad?`
Because `false` is equal to `nil` so it will consider that is a nil object and will not crash.

To better understand selectors read this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Selector.html) about selectors.

Comment: Just note that `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]` can be shorted to `@YES` with the current Clang compiler.